# Error 403 when clicking "Share"

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Error 403 for webpage snippet when clicking "Share"

This happens on some but not all pages.

For example on [this page](http://www.tenstars.ru/films/reviews/film-ucelevshij-treiler-obzor-2014.html)

When you click "share", it opens [this](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?src=sp&u=http://www.tenstars.ru/films/reviews/film-ucelevshij-treiler-obzor-2014.html&t=%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%20%22%D0%A3%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%22:%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%204-%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%20-%20TenStars.ru&description&picture) in a popup

With the following error:

[image: Facebook 403 share error]

> 403 - Error: 403
>
> ... If you are experiencing errors... Please contact the administrator...
>
> WWW.TENSTARS.RU

The problem disappears if I open the page in the facebook debugger:

**NOTE: DO NOT open the page in the facebook debugger, it will remove the error and others will not be able to see it!**

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

But the error re-appears on a different page.

I tried using the official share code but that didn't help.

I suspect that the problem is caused by the facebook crawler failing to download some page and then using a "failed" copy, but I would like to debug/figure out the actual reason.

Comment: One specific issue can be mod_security, as the Facebook bot is broken :
Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). String match "bytes=0-" at REQUEST_HEADERS:Range. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf"] [line "427"] [id "958291"] [rev "2"] [msg "Range: field exists and begins with 0."] [data "bytes=0-524287"] [severity "WARNING"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.8"] [maturity "6"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup some Facebook bot logging

```
Facebook bot tracking in /index.php
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

Clicking the Facebook share button does not trigger the facebook bot to download the page.
The webpage [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669313/does-facebook-need-to-actually-crawl-a-page-for-og-to-work) (Crawl) by the Facebook bot is triggered by the JavaScript SDK, and you can't load the share windows without the SDK.
The bot crawl is also triggered by [publishing the URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/) anywhere on facebook.

Facebook SDK

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=368997699815031";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Facebook downloads 2 pages with every 1 request (depends on the SDK config):

```
[2014-03-13 10:34:57][facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)] /films/events/mtv-movie-awards-2014.html
[2014-03-13 10:34:59][facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)] /films/events/mtv-movie-awards-2014.html?fb_locale=ru_RU
```

If Facebook downloads a page with an error status, Facebook will not re-download it unless you download it with the [Facebook lint debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) or some unknown to me timeout runs out. (unless you specify this timeout manually in [og:ttl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#u_0_1f))

In my case the facebook SDK requested the page while it was still being edited and cached the 403 response that it was giving.

The preview/story (or whatever you call it) shows the same text and status code that your website returned when the Facebook bot downloaded the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

See your htaccess file, and test the RewriteCond.
This is the cause of this error 403 and share facebook.

You can test your share page with the facebook tool : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

scrape again using this link
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
and make sure you have facebook Meta tags present, such as og:url, og:type, og:title, og:description etc. for example show below,

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.kktcfidan.com" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="K&#xfc;&#xe7;&#xfc;k bir hediye, b&#xfc;y&#xfc;k bir iyilik." />
<meta property="og:description" content="Sevdiklerine ve do&#x11f;aya verece&#x11f;in hediye yemye&#x15f;il bir gelecek olsun." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.kktcfidan.com/assets/images/facebook_share_photo.jpg" />
```

Hope this helps.